# sort command using multiple delimiters in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
sort -k 2 data.txt
```

Using the -k option, we can specify which fields to compare. However, fields are separated by white space. How do I modify my commands so I can make my delimiters white space and the colon ':' together?

For example,

```
james:ben tom:jamie
```

has 4 fields.

Expected input:
my data.txt file:

```
apple:tiger jack
orange:ant tom
pear:bird james
```

Expected output: using sort command with -k 2

```
orange:ant tom
pear:bird james
apple:tiger jack
```

Comment: Can you write your input and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

I'd be interested if you find a *proper* solution.  My current workaround for situations like these is modifying the input for sort and undo the modification afterwards:

```
printf "1:2 3:4\n2:3 4:1\n3:4 1:2\n4:1 2:3\n" |
  sed 's/:/ :/g' | sort -k 4 | sed 's/ :/:/g'
```

You can modify the number after `-k` to any number from 1 through 4.  Output will be sth like this (for 4):

```
2:3 4:1
3:4 1:2
4:1 2:3
1:2 3:4
```

Comment: Yours is a classical example of the Schwarzian transform though it might not be idempotent.  A somewhat more robust solution would be to extract the sort key as a separate field (tab separated maybe) and strip the entire first field after sorting.